# How to switch to another column when exporting to csv

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, whitespace, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I need to export some data to MS Excel. I laod the data to the ByteArray and then I print it to the file. Nevertheless I wasn't able to find out, how to switch to next column. I tried '\t', "\t", Char(9) and many others, but what I get in excel file is only unknown character symbol ... "\n" works just fine...
I'm programming this app in AS3, if it could have any connection..

Comment: Have you tried a comma?  ','

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV stands for "comma separated values". The default delimiter for columns is the comma (`,`).

Also, you can designate what character you want to use as the column delimiter (tabs, for example), when importing to excel

Comment: Your answer guided me to the right solution. Nevertheless the delimiter wasn't comma, but semicolon (';'). So it would be nice to update your answer, that sometimes is needed to use semicolon istead of comma, so your answer can stay as a solution.